# mTLS connects to invalid SAN-IP

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate

mTLS establishes a connection - even if certificate-IP and server-IP mismatch.

The question: Is there an OpenSSL/libreSSL function/option to enforce IP-matching?

###### Steps to reproduce (using openssl to demonstrate):

```
wget http://doppelbauer.name/server.key
wget http://doppelbauer.name/server.crt
wget http://doppelbauer.name/ca.crt
```

###### Inspect: SAN IP=10.20.30.40

```
openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -text

        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:10.20.30.40
```

###### Server on port 8080

```
openssl s_server -key server.key -cert server.crt -CAfile ca.crt -accept 8080
```

###### HERE BE DRAGONS: Client connects - event if connecting-IP (127.0.0.1) does not match certificate-IP '10.20.30.40'

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080 -CAfile ca.crt
```

###### Certificates (redundant)

```
# server.key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

# server.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

# ca.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: "TLS establishes a connection - even if certificate-IP and server-IP mismatch." Certainly not a "feature" of the protocol, depends on your client. So, as is, your question is not really about programming, hence offtopic here.

Comment: Clearified the question. How **mTLS** server/client IPs could be enforced using openssl/libressl is definitely a programming issue (openssl command-line  helps to demonstrate the issue)

Comment: " using openssl/libressl is definitely a programming issue " No, not in its current stance because there is no *program* in your question using openssl, you are just calling from command line. Your question is even spelled out "how do I configure", which is clearly not programming related.

Comment: Clearified again. It is programming related (we use libre-ssl)

Comment: No it is is not clarified. Show the **program** using LibreSSL, and what fails. Not the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the OpenSSL `s_client` documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html):

> **OPTIONS**
>
> ...
>
> -verify depth
>
> The verify depth to use. This specifies the maximum length of the server certificate chain and turns on server certificate verification. Currently the verify operation continues after errors so all the problems with a certificate chain can be seen. As a side effect the connection will never fail due to a server certificate verify failure.
>
> -verify_return_error
>
> Return verification errors instead of continuing. This will typically abort the handshake with a fatal error.

Adding something like `-verify 1 -verify_return_error` to your command should enable connection failure on a failed certificate verification, and that *should* check the IP SAN on the server's cert.

Comment: No; OpenSSL cert check by default does not include host identity(s). **See _also_ `-verify_ip`** on the [openssl-]verify man page, as referenced from s_client. And BTW 1.0.2 is no longer supported, although this feature(?) is unchanged in supported versions.